JAR cannot find a suitable driver for SQLite JDBC connection even though it is in the classpath
Let me begin by saying that I've gone through half a dozen questions with the same subject and through the answers that tell to add SQLite JDBC driver to the pom.xml file. My case is different, because the dependency is already there and has always been, since the creation of the project. It runs in Netbeans but does not run on the command line.
Here's my pom. I removed other dependencies that have no bearing on the question and left only Xerial:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myorg</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.myorg.myproj.myclass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>com.myorg.myproj.myclass</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
          <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
          <version>3.46.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <name>myproj</name>
    <description>myproj is</description>
</project>

Here's my manifest. I also removed the irrelevant dependencies from the classpath:
Created-By: Maven JAR Plugin 3.3.0
Build-Jdk-Spec: 11
Class-Path: <some jars> sqlite-jdbc-3.46.0.1.jar slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar <more jars>
Main-Class: com.myorg.myproj.mymainclass

I do notice that slf4j is in the classpath but not in pom.xml but this should not be a problem, should it? If it's on the classpath, that should suffice, should it not?
What is still missing for this JAR to be self-contained and run on the command line?

java command documentation: “When you use -jar, the specified JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other class path settings are ignored.” Running with java -jar (which happens to be what occurs when you double-click a .jar file, usually) will cause the manifest’s Class-Path line to be ignored. Either provide a script that does java -cp myproject-1.0-0.jar;sqlite-jdbc-3.46.0.1.jar;slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar com.myorg.myproj.mymainclass, or jlink your application.

@VGR - the Class-Path entry in the manifest will not be ignored when using java -jar; the environment variable CLASSPATH (and -cp option) will be ignored (tested and used since last century, including with database drivers)

( also note that the entries of the Class-Path line are relative to the location of the JAR file, not necessarily to the current working directory [when using java -jar] )

@user85421 I just tested it, and you are correct.  Class-Path is still recognized when using the -jar option.

Do you have that sqlite-jdbc-3.46.0.1.jar and slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar in the same directory as your JAR? If not, they won't be found, and thus not loaded.

re-reading the question: "JAR to be self-contained"  - does that mean that you don't have/want the additional JAR files (like sqlite-jdbc-3.46.0.1.jar slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar) ??

@user85421 I want the JAR to run just like it does when I hit Ctrl-F5 in Netbeans. I do not care for anything else. It has to run, but how or why it runs is not of concern to me. That's how it is supposed to be when developing software with IDEs: they build things, and we click on them and run. In decent IDEs that is done by building, in mediocre IDEs it is done by publishing, and in crappy IDEs it does not work at all as seems to be the case with Netbeans. I don't know if this is a Maven thing. If it is then replace Netbeans with Maven in the previous sentence.

@MarkRotteveel Neither Netbeans nor Maven have put any other JARs in the target directory where the project.jar resides. Having built the app, do I now have to chase each and every JAR that I've been adding to the project as dependencies and manually copy them to the same directory? Should not Netbeans or Maven do that for me like Visual Studio does?

@BusterZo Only if you configure it do so, see How can I create an executable/runnable JAR with dependencies using Maven? (where I think the second answer is more applicable than the first).

@MarkRotteveel Ah, thanks, I did not know that Maven is that retarded. Their devs probably believe that we enjoy extra challenges and spend our time playing.
